# in the assault on dragons keep dlc in borderlands 2, does the handsom wizard drop the impaler?

Tags: borderlands-2

I have been told several times by my friend that the handsome wizard drops the impaler.Is this true? does he drop any legendaries at all? and if so which one/ones?

Comment: This is mentioned multiple times on [the wiki](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Impaler). Does this mean you don't consider the wiki a source or you didn't try searching it?

Answer (score 0):

from the wiki
http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Handsome_Sorcerer

The lootsplosion after the battle may drop multiple legendary items.
He has a similar loot pool to The Warrior, with an increased chance to drop:
Handsome Jack's Mask heads (legendary variant),
Volcano,
Impaler,
Leech,
Conference Call,
Flakker,
Fire Bee.